# Link to developer's apps

Tags: objective-c, app-store, tvos, apple-tv

How do I open the App Store on the Apple TV to show all the apps created by a specific developer?

The iOS way, `http://appstore.com/DEVNAME`, does not work on Apple TV.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
NSString* url = @"some url";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of a developer,

> https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1074241891

To get all apps by that developer,

> https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1074241891&entity=software

To get the apps based on localization,

> https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1074241891&entity=software&country=gb
>
> or
>
> https://itunes.apple.com/gb/lookup?id=514675684&entity=software

I don't know why it is currently making me download a js file, it is suppose to display JSON response in browser? Maybe just temporary?